# Copy SQLITE file from download folder to my app folder ANDROID 11

Tags: java, android, mediastore

before android 10 i can restore my database from any folder now when i create my fileinputstream and error becomes: /storage/emulated/0/Download/bd/bd.sqlite: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), I dont understan how give permision with MediaStore

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bdOrigen);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PathDestino);

        // transferir bytes al backup
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
```

Comment: How did that file land in Download folder? Did your app do it? Do you understand why your app has no permission?

Comment: Hi blackapp my app do it, i have to do a backup from my sqlite en some folder that the user can see i choose download folder, after that i have to restore the sqlite from download forlder too, i understand that download folder is public and i can read from there?

Comment: If your app can create/write a file in the public Download folder then it can surely read it. Why ask? I think you forgot to tell why you restore and when.

Comment: Use FIle.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

No simple answer here, you will have to start reading up on Storage Access Framework as i think Scoped Storage will not meet your requirements

Comment: Thanks, Why I can read from download folder i guess is public.